# JavaScript-TypeError: Cannot add property __id, object is not extensible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I defined a HOC React component and save it as a **tsx** file.

```
const Hoc = WrappedComponent => class extends WrappedComponent {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.__id = ''
  }
}
```

Once deliver it to the compiler, error would be cast.

```
TypeError: Cannot add property __id, object is not extensible
```

Comment: The error is coming from whatever argument you pass for the `WrappedComponent` parameter. The following does not throw: `const Hoc = WrappedComponent => class extends WrappedComponent {constructor(props, context) {super(props, context); this.__id = '';}};` and then `new Hoc(class {})`